# Change log level in jboss 7.1 without restarting the server using web consle interface

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss7.x

I want to change log level in standalone.xml using web console interface in jboss 7.1.1 without stopping the server.Same thing,I am able to do using CLI commonds as follows:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999/]/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-           attribute(name=level,value=<<log level value>>)
```

My logging subsystem in standalone.xml is as follows:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
```

Please suggest !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following steps:

1. Enter to web console (`http://<host>:9990`)
2. Select Profile
3. Select Core/Logging
4. Select Tab Handler
5. Edit and change the log level

See image below.

[image]

Comment: This does not change anything without a restart or reload.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart the server.  You can simply reload.

From the CLI, :reload

From the Management Console, select "Reload

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: The StackOverflow image adding utility rots.

Comment: But it also disturb the running system. Reload also shuts down the server. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46742389/5010153

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  What I'm suggesting here seems to be a contradiction.  If so, I will delete it.  Again, thanks, Annette!

Answer (score 0):

My method does not need to restart; you need to change 3 places:

- root logger level(to be below your desired level; for example you want DEBUG, root logger needs to be DEBUG or TRACE or lower)
- the actual, specific logger you need(like `com.app.data`, to DEBUG; if there is no such, add)
- the log handler(like `CONSOLE` or `FILE`, to DEBUG)

However it does not persists after restart if you only change in Management Web Console; to make it persistent, do it in `standalone.xml`.