# WildFly CLI command to reload a deployment

Tags: command-line-interface, wildfly

I can restart the whole WildFly server running the following Java code.
But I want to just  reload a deployment called 'test.war'. How could it be done?

```
public void flushall() throws IOException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "cmd /c start C:\\wildfly\\bin\\jboss-cli.bat --connect /subsystem=datasources/data-source=FirebirdPool/:flush-all-connection-in-pool "
    );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call the `redeploy` operation on the correct deployment node.

The CLI command looks like:

```
/deployment=test.war:redeploy()
```

It means in your case:

```
"cmd /c start C:\\wildfly\\bin\\jboss-cli.bat -c /deployment=test.war:redeploy"
```

Comment: why do you need to redeploy the application? It's not enough to simply disable/enable the application with `deployment disable` /  `deployment enable` commands?

Comment: Please specify the version. /deployment=[WAR]:redeploy() doesn't seem to be available in Wildfly 18.

Comment: It's available in the WildFly 18. If you use domain mode, then you have to specify in which server group you want to do the redeploy. E.g. `/server-group=main-server-group/deployment=test.war:redeploy`

Answer (score 4):

To restart JBoss or WildFly using command line interface (CLI):

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command=:shutdown(restart=true)
```

The same command without the restart parameter will simply shutdown JBoss and WildFly:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command=:shutdown
```

To reload JBoss and WildFly configuration using JBoss CLI:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command=:reload
```

---

There is a difference between `:reload` and `:shutdown(restart=true)` commands.

- `:reload` shuts down JBoss and starts it again without JVM restart.
- `:shutdown(restart=true)` restarts whole JVM process of the JBoss server.

Comment: How does this work if i have multiple instances of Wildfly and i only want to stop one of them. (i.e. one installation of wildfly but several running instances per WAR file)

Comment: Running multiple instances of Wildfly is possible, and you will have to add offset to ports that is opens.  Having different ports, with command you connect to specific instance and you can control that one. WAR files deployment and undeploy is also controllable per instance - see command with deploy, undeploy and redeploy.