# JBoss EAP 6 - Cannot set debug level loging, JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - "JBAS011539: Log level DEBUG# Secrets is invalid."

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I cannot set DEBUG logging level for my JBoss EAP; web console needs passwords so I try to set environment variables. But this error appears:

> 11:58:38,048 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
>
> 11:58:38,072 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 3.3.12.Final-redhat-2
>
> 2023-01-02 11:58:38,088 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) - JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
> ("subsystem" => "logging"),
> ("logger" => "com.example")
> ]) - failure description: "JBAS011539: Log level DEBUG# Secrets is invalid."
>
> 2023-01-02 11:58:38,089 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) - JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
> ("subsystem" => "logging"),
> ("logger" => "com.example")
> ]) - failure description: "JBAS011539: Log level DEBUG# Secrets is invalid."

I set env var, because `standalone.xml` uses it.

```bash
$ docker exec -i 53 grep "example" /opt/data/fuse/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
            <logger category="com.example">
                <level name="${app.logging.loggers.example.level:INFO}"/>
```

I set it in docker-compose file

```yaml
 environment:
   APP_LOGGING_LOGGERS_EXAMPLE_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

So, what is the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: That does look odd, but the case and pattern should match. I don’t believe it changes the system properties to environment variables.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you mean about the part of system props vs. env vars.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing from my phone. What I mean is I don't think the `app.logging.loggers.example.level` will be transformed to `APP_LOGGING_LOGGERS_EXAMPLE_LEVEL`. I think you'd want to change your expression to `APP_LOGGING_LOGGERS_EXAMPLE_LEVEL:INFO`.

Comment: I cannot change the key in the XML; it comes from a base image, and our jib folder seems not allowing me to replace that file in the base image, maybe permission problem. What I can do is to set env var in docker-compose.yaml; and when I do it like `app.xxx.xxx`, it says "bash: bad substitution". I think `.` is not allowed for env vars.

Comment: Hmmm... ...yeah. I'm trying to think of a way to work around that. I'm not sure where the "# Secrets" part would be coming from.

Comment: OK @JamesR.Perkins I think I have found out why. Other scripts are doing echo into the properties files like `echo '# Secrets ' >> xxxx` and because my prop is the last line, I guess it has no new line after that and I see `# Secrets` are appended after the last line. Let me fix it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out why. Other scripts are doing echo into the properties files like `echo '# Secrets ' >> xxxx` and then, find some secret and also echo after that line. And because no secret is found, this `# Secrets`  becomes the last line of my properties file. And then it is interpreted as logging level. And after changing the script of echo, it is working and no more errors.

Besides I have found out the password and username of JBoss EAP Management console, so I can change logging level there. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76218654/4537090) to learn how to do it properly.